# Miktex error: Couldn't connect to server

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

I'm trying to install some Latex packages with Miktex package manager. However, this notification keep bumping up. I tried changing the repo, but it couldn't connect to the server, so I couldn't get the list of links to other repos:
[image: Miktex bug]
Can someone help me fixing this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: this is probably only temporary (from yesterday evening).  be patient,  and try again today afternoon :-)

Comment: I've been having the same problem, but it seems to be resolved now. (The MikTex site itself wasn't accessible either until a little bit ago.)

Comment: Some firewalls block ftp. Are you behind such a firewall? If so, go somewhere else, connect, and ensure that your repo uses http. Note: Isn't it annoying that you can't get a list of repos, unless you are already connected to one?